# Sum values based on groupID

Tags: sql

Please consider the following table `Data`

```
#ID    groupID    value
------------------------
  1    100        -22.50
  2    100        -10.00
  3    130         15.00
  4    140        -11.25
  5    130        -10.00
  6    210          5.75
```

I need the sum per `groupID` added as an additional column, as follows:

```
#ID    groupID    value     groupSum
------------------------------------
  1    100        -22.50      -32.50
  2    100        -10.00      -32.50
  3    130         15.00        5.00
  4    140        -11.25      -11.25
  5    130        -10.00        5.00
  6    210          5.75        5.75
```

If I wanted just to sum per `groupID`, I could do a `GROUP BY` on `groupID` and a `SUM` on `value`, resulting in

```
groupID    groupSum
-------------------
100        -32.50
130          5.00
140        -11.25
210          5.75
```

But this is explicitly not what I need, and I don't know how to start to have a query which select the whole table, but then in the output has the `sum` of the group after added to each record.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Have you looked at `GROUPBY`? See the SQL documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Window Partitioning.

```
select
    *
    ,sum([value]) over(partition by [groupid]) as [GroupTotal]
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
SELECT d.#ID, d.groupID, d.value, g.groupSum
FROM Data d LEFT JOIN (SELECT groupID, SUM(value) groupSum
                       FROM Data
                       GROUP BY groupID) g ON d.groupID = g.groupID
```

Answer (score 0):

If window functions are not available you can use self-join

```
 select d1.*, sum(d2.value) as groupsum
 from data d1
 left join data d2 on d1.groupID = d2.groupID
 group by d1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should select with Group By to calculate sum of value from your table.

```
select groupID, sum(value) as SS
from table_name
group by groupID
```

Secondly, you should RIGHT JOIN (to participate all rows of table) the above query with first table to add the sum column as 
 new column to it. So final result of your question is:

```
select t2.id,t2.groupid,t1.SS 
from
(select groupid, sum(value) as SS
from table_name group by groupid) t1
RIGHT JOIN table_name t2
ON t1.groupid=t2.groupid
order by t2.id
```

you can use LEFT JOIN instead. Just switch the place of table_name with query in the final answer.